# What to expect when flagging duplicate questions

Tags: support, questions, duplicate-questions, merged-questions

I recently was searching for a solution to a problem I was having with an Android app I'm developing. I ended up coming across several questions that basically were the same as mine:

1. [Android : Multi touch and TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8073803/1008035)
2. [Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4481226/1008035)
3. [Android : Floating Clickable Icon over Screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3732935/1008035)

After reviewing each question and its answers, I wasn't able to resolve my issue. I worked through the issue and ended up coming up with my own solution. I answered question #1 with my solution, but I believe question #2 and #3 would also benefit from my solution.

I flagged my answer and noted that the three questions should probably be merged and that my answer was beneficial to the other two questions. My flag was deemed helpful, but what happens now?

I know my small group of questions pales in comparison to the entire Stack Overflow community, but what should I expect to happen next (if anything) and what's the reasonable time-line? I know people are probably viewing #2 or #3 and not finding #1 and would benefit from my answer.

Comment: If they would benefit from exactly the same answer, aren't the questions duplicates to begin with?

Comment: They are duplicates and I noted that when I flagged them (Editing my question to clarify this).  I'm just wondering what happens next.  Will the questions be linked together?